# How to use nested repeaters to dynamically add/remove data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on `ASP.NET Web Forms` application. The business logic is - I have many users and each user my have several accounts. I have a view where the user of the system may add people and when adding someone I want to show (I chose table for this) the name of the person and all the accounts associated with him. So the final output should be something like:

```
<span>Person name</span>
<table>
<tr>Account 1 info..</tr>
<tr>Account 2 info..</tr>
..
</table>

<span>Another Person name</span>
<table>
<tr>Account 1 info..</tr>
<tr>Account 2 info..</tr>
..
</table>
```

So I decided that maybe this is relatively standard with two nested repeaters. So I add two of them in my view:

```
<asp:Repeater id="RpAccountsToDistraint" 
  OnItemDataBound="RpAccountsToDistraint_ItemDataBound"
  runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <fieldset><legend>Person name</legend>
  <asp:Repeater ID="RpInnerAccountsToDistraint" 
    OnItemDataBound="RpInnerAccountsToDistraint_ItemDataBound"
    runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Account</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Account Amount..</td>
          ..
      </tbody>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
      </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

I won't write the whole markup since I think it's standrd and also I think that my problem is in on the server side. And the problem is that each time I add a person to the list the new `fieldset` is correctly added from the first repeater but also for now the logic is hardcoded in my code behind so it's not something that I can relate to. But the actual information is taken from the database each time a new person is added and here is the problem - when I add the first person - I get one `fieldset` with the correct account information. When I add second and so on, the new fieldsets are added correctly to the page, but each of them contains the account infiormation for the last selected user.

So from what I see, the problem is that I can't feed the inner repeater in a proper way. Recently I had to work a lot with Repeaters so I get used to persisting old data in `ViewState` adding new data, keeping the old one and so on. I have object called `ClientAccount` that I use for the repeater. I tried many data structures to store the data so it's displayed properly - `List<ClientAccount`,`List<List<ClientAccount>>`, `Dictionary<int, List<ClientAccount>>`, while debugging I can see that at some point all the information - old and new is collected but then only the information for the last user is shown. Ay suggestions on how to improve my code, or example that covers topic similar to this would be highly appreciated. Here is what I use in code behind:

```
protected void ParentRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem 
                      || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
      Repeater innerRepeater = 
        (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("RpInnerAccountsToDistraint");
      if (null == feedAccountRptr)
      {
        feedAccountRptr = new Dictionary<int, List<ClientAccount>>();
      }

      if (!(((Dictionary<int, List<ClientAccount>>)ViewState["theAccounts"]) == null))
      {
      feedAccountRptr = ((Dictionary<int, List<ClientAccount>>)ViewState["theAccounts"]);
      }
            int count = feedAccountRptr.Count;
            feedAccountRptr.Add(++count, GetAccountsForClient());
            ViewState["theAccounts"] = feedAccountRptr;
            innerRepeater.DataSource = GetAccountsForClient();// feedAccountRptr;
            innerRepeater.DataBind();
        }
```

and

```
protected void InnerRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem 
                      || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
    //Just take the values from my controls but actually not doing anything else
```

the las thing, the variable `feedAccountRptr` is a class member delcared at the beining of the class `Dictionary<int, List<ClientAccount>> feedAccountRptr;`.

Comment: What does `GetAccountsForClient()` look like? I would think in that method you would want to pass some sort of parameter related to the parent repeater item.

Comment: @j.f. Yeah, it executes simple select on the database with the id of the newly added person. I use this method to get the data for each new person. The old data is stored in a `ViewState` variable.

Comment: Is that ViewState key used anywhere in `GetAccountsForClient()`? Can we see that code? I'm still not entirely sure what that ViewState key is used for or why it's necessary.

Comment: `feedAccountRptr = ((Dictionary<int, List<ClientAccount>>)ViewState["theAccounts"]);` and `ViewState["theAccounts"] = feedAccountRptr;` - Does the using of ViewState now making sense?

Comment: I see how you are using it. I don't completely understand _why_ you're using it. My guess is there is something fishy within `GetAccountsForClient()` since whatever is returning from there is what is being bound to the inner repeater.

Comment: As I said, `GetAccountsForClient()` is just a simple helper method which is exactly `SELECT value1, value2, value3, value4 FROM Accounts WHERE Id = 1(for example)` the result is attached fo my `ClientAccount` class, so I end up with `List<ClientAccount>`. There's nothing fishy, just e simple `SELECT` to get the data for all account of user. The problem here is how to make the repeater draw the information for the previous user plus the new information, because as I wrote the most I get is to show only the info for the last user.

Comment: Ok, I may be getting confused. Is the problem with the inner repeater or the outer repeater? I'm seeing reasons applying to both.

Comment: The problem was that I can't pass all the values and expect the repeater to find out how I want to render them. So on each call to `ItemDataBound` handler I have to pass only what I want to be rendered on this iteration. Nothing fishy in the methods or whatever. Just needed to find out, how I am supposed to feed the repeater.